# how to post data from app script to cloud function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-403

I am new to app script and I need to create a script that sends to cloud function a new word in the spreadsheet via post method.

The cloud function is done and works but I need help with app script

So far I have this but incomplete because I dont know how the authentication works and dont know how to capture the value to pass it to the payload

```
function postDataToUrl() {
  var url = 'myCloudFunctionURL'; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var word = range.getValue(); // Get the value of the active range
  
  var payload = {
    "word": word // Use the retrieved value as the payload data
  };
  
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I get 403 Forbidden. Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Is there a error?

Comment: I`ve improved my code and get an error 403, edited the question

Comment: You need send a Bearer oauth token. `ScriptApp.getOauthToken()` in `headers`